# Will the hats retain forever? Or will reward a Badge？

Tags: discussion

So what on earth is the reward? Or just a list of HATS??
In fact, I prefer a badge.

Comment: There's a blog post - linked in the right [Winter Bash 2014](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/12/winter-bash-2014/) - it explains all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hats will only remain during the period of the Winterbash.

Some of the hats may well have the same criteria (or almost the same criteria) as badges, so if you gain a certain hat you could also gain a badge (or at least be on the way to gaining a badge).

They are meant as a bit of end of year fun. If you don't want to participate then click on the "I hate hats" link at the bottom of the snowflake drop-down.

Comment: Cheers!  happly new years!